# MVC 5 - Add Methods to @User from View

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

From the cshtml page out of the box you can use User.IsInRole() to check to see if a user is within a role. In my application I am using a custom IIdentity user and implement my own UserStore, UserManager, RoleManager etc.

On my custom identity  i add custom claims for things like Application etc.

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync( UserManager<CustomIdentity, int> manager )
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync( this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie );
            // Add custom user claims here          
            userIdentity.AddClaim( new Claim( CustomClaimTypes.Application, "Application1" ) );

            return userIdentity;
        }
```

How can i add additional methods to either User or User.Identity for things like User.HasApplication("string")

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extensions class an access via the following

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static bool GetIdentityExtentsion(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public static bool GetIdentityExtentsion2( this IPrincipal principal )
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

GetIdentiyExtentsion will be visible @User.Identity.GetIdentityExtensions

GetIdentityExtensions2 will be visible @User.GetIdentityExtensions2

Be sure to add the @using Namespace within the view. I have tried it within the Views / Web.Config and it is not showing the extensions for some reason.